# Why are PNG and TIFF formats treated differently than JPG and GIF by a webserver?

Tags: images, webserver, http

- I observed that my web-browser kept download PNG and TIFF images, while happily displayed JPG and GIF when I clicked on a link to that image. Ex. `http://somesite.com/image.<format>`
- On closer inspection of the HTTP response headers, I observed that the difference in the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers was causing this behavior.

Anyone know why these are treated differently?

---

PNG:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 01:33:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (CentOS)
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename*=UTF-8''PNG.png
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

JPG:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 01:34:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (CentOS)
Content-Disposition: inline;filename*=UTF-8''JPG.jpg
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

GIF:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 01:31:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (CentOS)
Content-Disposition: inline;filename="GIF.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif
```

Comment: Your browser decides whether it will download the file or just display it in place. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @user3767013 - Tested on IE and Chrome. I believe the behavior is almost universal. Note that the images were not embedded into the HTML in `<img>` tags but were links to the file.

Answer (score 3):

The web server that is serving the files is not configured correctly to serve those image types.  The generic, "unknown" Content Type is `application/octet-stream`. The browser uses the `Content-Type` header to decide how to handle the file,and since it doesn't have anything to handle it, it just downloads the file.

Most Apache installations have a `mime.types` file in their configuration that handles the file extension to content type mapping.

The server is also setting the [`Content-Disposition`](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) header to `attachment` which will also cause the browser to download the file instead of display it inline.